# How to get database value selected in select option in jsp?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, select

I have a database contain value as :

```
doc_id     doc_type

 123        Report
```

Table definition as:

```
doc_id   varchar(100) NOT NULL

doc_type  varchar(80) NOT NULL
```

I want the database value as option selected ie if I have select options as:

```
  Report
  Note
  PPT
  Others
```

Default option to be selected as Report

```
   <div class="col-md-4 mb-3 form-group">
                <label for="validationDefaultUsername">Document Type  *</label>      
                <select class="custom-select form-control" name="doc_type"  required>            
                    <option selected>Select Document Type</option>
                    <option >Report</option>
                    <option >Note</option> 
                    <option >PPT/PPX</option>     
                    <option >Others</option>   
                </select>
</div>
```

How to get database value as option selected?

Comment: if you are using javascript/JQuery then use Ajax to get value from the server after the option is clicked

Comment: @binz Your question is not clear do you want the default selected option from the database

Comment: @ Manoj Ramanan .Yes

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="docz">
            <c:forEach items="${docList}" var="doc">
                <option value="${doc.doc_id}"
                    <c:if test="${doc.doc_type eq 'Report'}">selected="selected"</c:if>                        >
                    ${doc.doc_type}
                </option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
```

Comment: I am using jsp.

Comment: it is recommened to use JSTL along with JSP for code maintainability and readability. However, how are you populating data on client side ? are you using javascript or jquery along with HTML ?

Comment: I want to use database value as default option.How to do so